# Animate a group of elements in NativeScript + Vue

Tags: vue.js, animation, nativescript

I have a list like this: (it will generated by a **for** loop, and each row is related to a unique **ref** : *ref="'dataRow'+id"* )

```
<GridLayout class="mainList">

    <ListView
     for="( sentence , id ) in sentences" 
    ><v-template><StackLayout>

        <GridLayout 
         class="dataRow"
         :ref="'dataRow'+id"
         @tap="tapAction( 'dataRow'+id )"
        >

            ...

        </GridLayout>

    </StackLayout></v-template></ListView>

</GridLayout>
```

I would like to expand each row of Data by tapping on it, and I acheive that by this piece of the code:

```
tapAction ( dR ) {

   this.$refs[dR].nativeView.animate ( {
       height: 300 ,
       duration: 200 ,
       curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeIn
    } ) 

}
```

(BTW I noticed it expands multiple rows!! I think it is related to the nature of **ListView** but it seems a bit bizarre to me while I used unique **ref** for each row of data! any suggestion for this issue would be helpful, but my actual question is something else.)

**my problem is this:**

I woud like to collapse all expanded rows at once , but I can Not find a proper way to do that! my first thought was that to set all elements by the **dataRow** calssName to the default value, but I can Not do that as simple as we can perform in a web browser with css + js.

Comment: Are you testing on iOS / Android? At least Android might run layouts again upon updates, iOS might not. So you may end up seeing expanded rows while it's actually collapsed when the ListView tries to reuse items. You may have to use native APIs to animate right index, I will see if I can setup an example. It may take time.

Comment: I am testing on Android.
Do you mean by "You may have to use native APIs to animate right index," that there is no way to prevent this problem by NativeScript itself? about my actual problem (animate by className) is there any solution?